# Android Emulator camera hangs after sometime

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an android camera app. Whenever i open the app the camera opens normally then after a few seconds most of the times it hangs and ultimately the emulator shows not responding after a while. Very rarely it operates normally when i open the app. Not only my custom camera app but i tested the default emulator camera, it also hangs after a while when it is opened. I don't know what is happening wrong. On real devices my camera works fine. So the issue is not with the app but the camera of my emulator.

Comment: I don't know why my question is marked negative.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug with certain versions of the emulator. For example, camera app hangs on emulator version `29.3.2.0 (build_id 6083285)` regardless of the whether it's emulated or set to `Webcam0`, but works fine on `29.2.1.0 (build_id 5889189)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but only on one of my laptops. It seems someting is connected with computer graphic card.
Try to change  paramather Automatic with Software-GLES 2.0 in  AVD manager-emulated perfromance. IT's slower but it works.